# How to prevent images from being copied from an iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone

My App will require the use of about 500 images and this number could possibly grow. Those images are read-only and the user won't add any pictures while using the app.

Image sizes will probably range between 50 to 250k .

I want to prevent the images from being copied by someone exploring the bundle resources for example.

So far I am thinking of putting all the images in a SQLite database and then encrypt it using SQLCipher for example.

Does this seems a bit over the top ?

In your opinion what would be the best solution ?

Could Apple reject it ?

I understand that people can always take screenshots, etc... but I just want to make it difficult without it being a nightmare to code and use.

Cheers,
Duz

Comment: Honestly, anyone who's willing to go to the trouble of using a bundle explorer is probably willing to go to the trouble of snapping a screenshot. If you want to prevent people from using your images, watermark them. Otherwise, it's really not worth the hassle.

Comment: If someone steals your images, you can probably complain to Apple and have their apps pulled anyway. Watermarking all of your images won't lead to a very good user experience, and putting your images in a SQLite database and then encrypting it seems way over the top.

Comment: Exploring the bundle is very easy: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10213683-233.html
I don't think someone would take my images and put them in another app, I was more thinking of someone putting them in a zip on the web (watermarked or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider cropping your images into smaller tiles and regrouping them into a bigger image when it's time to display.

In addition to the benefit of prohibiting a direct copy, it also improve performance for big images.

Refer to the Apple `ScrollViewSuite` sample for implementation details.